# How to load an external configuration with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently learning how to work with Spring Boot. Until now I never used Frameworks like Spring and used files directly (FileInputStream, etc.)

So here is the case: I have some dynamic configuration values like OAuth tokens. I want to use them inside of my application but I have no clue how to realize this with Spring.

Here is some code to make clear what I'm searching for:

```
@Config("app.yaml")
public class Test {
    @Value("app.token")
    private String token;
    private IClient client;

    public Test(String token) {
        this.client = ClientFactory.build(token).login();
    }
}
```

Sure, this example is very plain. Here I want to get the value "token" dynamically from a YAML configuration file. This file must be accessible for the user and not included in the JAR file.

I also found that doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html but I have now idea how to apply this to my project.

How can I achive this? Thank you in advance :)

**Edit:**

Here are some parts of my code:

**WatchdogBootstrap.java**

```
package de.onkelmorph.watchdog;

import org.springframework.boot.Banner.Mode;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:Beans.xml")
public class WatchdogBootstrap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(WatchdogBeans.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Mode.OFF);
        app.setWebEnvironment(false);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

**Beans.xml** (Located in default package)

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
</beans>
```

**Watchdog.java**

```
package de.onkelmorph.watchdog;

// Imports ...

@Component
@PropertySource("file:/watchdog.yml")
public class Watchdog {
    // ...

    // Configuration
    @Value("${watchdog.token}")
    private String token;

    public Watchdog() {
        System.out.println(this.token);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // ...
}
```

**watchdog.yml** (Located in src/main/resources)

```
watchdog:
  token: fghaepoghaporghaerg
```

Comment: I am not trying to be rude, but did you read the documentation? Is there anything specific about it that you need help with? Normally if you want to load an external configuration file, you would use something like `java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject` I would love to help, but I need to know which part that you require assistance with. Everything is pretty much well-explained in the documenatation that you refered to.

Comment: Hi kkflf and thanks for you reply! Sure, I read the docs but I think I didn't get them ... Is there a way to load the config without additional VM parameters? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, that is possible. You should take a look at `@PropertySource`. This annotation will allow you to load both internal and external configurations files. If your project span over multiple development environements, you should take a look at either profiling or using vm parameters, but do not focus on this until you got the configuration files working. Just keep in mind how to make your application configuration suitable for multiple work environments.

Comment: A quick note, in case you are not aware. Spring has a standard properties files: `application.properties`. If this file is not already present in your project, then you can add it to  `src/main/resources` if you are using Maven.

Comment: I have created a basic example and explanation as answer. If you need further assistance, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all your `Test` class should be annotated with `@Component` in order for it to be registered as a bean by spring (also make sure all your classes are under your main package - the main package is where a class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` reside).

Now you should either move all your properties to `application.yml` (`src/main/resources/application.yml`), that is picked automatically by spring boot (note that it should be `.yml` instead of `.yaml` or register a custom `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Example for `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
    Resource resource = new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource("classpath:application.yml");
    YamlPropertySourceLoader sourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
    PropertySource<?> yamlProperties = sourceLoader.load("yamlProperties", resource, null);
    propertySources.addFirst(yamlProperties);
    configurer.setPropertySources(propertySources);
    return configurer;
}
```

Now your properties should be loaded to spring's environment and they will be available for injection with `@Value` to your beans.

Comment: Hi @Tom and thanks for you support. I also tried your solution but it doesn't work for me ... I appended some code pieces in my question above, maybe there is a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hi, there are some problems with the code above. 1) do not mix XML and Java configuration, it makes a lot of problems and it is unneeded to define `annotation-config` because its the default. so you can remove `@ImportResource("classpath:Beans.xml")` 2) `@PropertySource` does not work with yaml. 3) The `@Bean` example I gave should either be in `WatchdogBootstrap.java` or in a `@Configuration` annotated class. 4) For file system resource use `new FileSystemResource(...)` instead of `new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource(...)`

Comment: If your file is in `src/main/resources` and you define this bean, it will work with `new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource("classpath:watchdog.yml");`

Comment: Hi Tom! 1) Resolved, but without `@ImportResource("classpath:Beans.xml")` the Beans.xml file won't be loaded. I moved the Beans.xml file to `/src/main/resources`. 2) Changed this to .properties, but I thought Spring will convert this internally? Thanks! :)

Comment: If you work completely with spring boot, `@SpringBootApplication` does `@ComponentScan` which captures all your beans under the base package. spring boot does not convert yaml when using `@PropertySource` unfortunately.

Comment: In your `SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(WatchdogBeans.class);` change `WatchdogBeans.class` to `WatchdogBootstrap.class`

Comment: Also try to use `SpringApplicationBuilder` for easier API.

Comment: Hi Tom, unfortunately there is no automatic component scan done. WatchdogBootstrap (which contains the `@SpringBootApplication`) should instantiate the `Watchdog` class which has the `@Component`annotation. But without `@ImportResource("classpath:Beans.xml")` the Beans.xml won't be loaded and without explicit bean definitions nothing will be instantiated. I'm out of ideas ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143296/discussion-between-tom-and-morph).

Comment: You have some spring legacy concepts, spring boot is a bit different and you should read some getting started about it or some documentations. I opened a chat if you want me to help clarify some of those concepts.

Answer (score 4):

You basically got three easy options.

1. Use `application.properties` which is Springs internal configuration file.
2. Load your own configuration file using `--spring.config.name` as VM parameter.
3. You can use `@PropertySource` to load either an internal or external configuration. `@PropertySource` only works with .properties config files. There is currently an open Jira ticket to implement yaml support. You can follow the progress here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13912

Notice, if you are using multiple yaml and/or properties files which contain common keys, the it will always use the definition of the key which was loaded last. This is why the below example uses two different keys. If it used the same key, then it would print out `PROPERTIES FILE` twice.

**Short simple code snippet:**

```
@Component
@PropertySource("file:/path/to/config/app.properties")
class Address{

    @Value("${addr.street}")
    private String street;

    @Value("${addr.city}")
    private String city;
}
```

**app.properties**

```
addr.street=Abbey Road
addr.city=London
```

**Extensive Example**

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        //Call class with properties
        context.getBean(WatchdogProperties.class).test();
        //Call class with yaml
        context.getBean(WatchdogYaml.class).test();
    }

    //Define configuration file for yaml
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
      PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
      yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("watchdog.yml"));
      propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
      return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

**WatchdogProperties.java**

```
@Component
//PropertySource only works for .properties files
@PropertySource("classpath:watchdog.properties")
public class WatchdogProperties{
    //Notice the key name is not the same as the yaml key
    @Value("${watchdog.prop.token}")
    private String token;

    public void test(){
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

**WatchdogYaml.java**

```
@Component
class WatchdogYaml{
    //Notice the key name is not the same as the properties key
    @Value("${watchdog.token}")
    private String token;

    public void test(){
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

**Properties and Yaml files**
Both of these files are located in `src/main/resources`

watchdog.yml:

```
watchdog:
  token: YAML FILE
```

watchdog.properties:

```
watchdog.prop.token=PROPERTIES FILE
```

**Output**

```
PROPERTIES FILE
YAML FILE
```

Comment: Fyi: I did not test the above code, as I am not able to do so atm. If anyone spots an error, please let me know.

Comment: Hi @kkflf and thanks for the support! Unfortunately it doesn't work so far ... I appended some code pieces in my question above. I'm using Maven to build the project and the watchdog.yml file is located at the projects root directory.

Comment: `@PropertySource("file:/watchdog.yml")` looks to be wrong. This is not the project root. Please change it to `@PropertySource("classpath:watchdog.yml")`

Comment: I would also suggest you to use to absolute path to your configuration file to make sure that PropertySource is working.

Comment: Please your yaml file: watchdog.yml

Comment: I appended the file to the question above

Comment: FYI, `@PropertySource` does not work with yaml, refer to spring documentation [yaml shortcomings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)

Comment: That is actually true. I forgot about that. There is however work in progress to make `@PropertySource` work with yaml, but this wont help OP currently.

Comment: @Morph I have updated my answer with a compilable version which you can try out and adapt to your project.