# Properties in dependent jar are not loaded in Environment object

Tags: spring-boot

I have spring boot executable jar (Jar1). This jar has a dependent jar (Jar2) in its lib folder which contains a properties file, let say it as jar2props.properties.

When I execute the Jar1 using `java -jar Jar1.jar`, the Jar2 classes are not able to load the properties in jar2props.properties. I am using `environment.getProperty("property1")` to get the properties value in jar2 classes.

But when I execute the Jar1 using `java -jar Jar1.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/jar1props.properties,classpath:/jar2props.properties` it is working fine.

Is there any other way to execute Jar1 successfully without specifying the spring.config.location explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

Long answer, you can also do it in code (like the example from my answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755380/how-to-load-an-external-configuration-with-spring-boot/43755660#43755660))

By default spring boot loads only application.properties/yml from your classpath and if you want it to load something else you need to tell him what to load and from where.

Look at this part of spring documentation for more information: [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: Thank you Tom for your reply. If we go with the approach that loading the properties file through code, do we need to write the piece of logic in Jar2 Configuration class? or in Jar1 Configuration class?

Comment: Jar1, you always configure everything in the jar that you run (the one that in the end will be run with `java -jar`)